# Facebook Pixel displays 'custom_data' with '_removed_' value

Tags: facebook, ember.js, analytics, pixel

I'm using ember-metrics to send custom event to Facebook Pixel.
This is my code:

```
this.get('metrics').trackEvent('FacebookPixel', {event:'FreeTrial', custom_data: { location:location, url:'free-trial', campaign:campaign}});
```

When I go to Facebook control panel I see the following:

```
Nov 11, 2019, 9:53 AM
iPhone
custom_data:_removed_,
```

similar issue described on Facebook Developer's board:
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/460685204654352/

Facebook have the following help pop-up for this field:
*The parameters sent with this event. Parameter values may be removed if they were hashed before being sent to Facebook, or contain sensitive information that we detect.*

Anyone had this issue before? What am I doing entirely wrong?

Comment: How does the network request to facebook look like? Could you copy one as fetch / curl and add it to your question? Did you checked that you don't that a [`metrics.context`](https://github.com/poteto/ember-metrics#context) anywhere in your app?

Comment: @jelhan thanks for your reply;
will query parameters i send help?
`id=99999999999&ev=JoinNow&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitename.com%2Fpage%2Fjoin-now&rl=&if=false&ts=1573513839108&cd%5Bcampaign%5D=empty&cd%5Bcustom_data%5D=%7B%22lcode%22%3A%222767%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22join-now-url%22%2C%22campaign%22%3A%22empty%22%7D&sw=1366&sh=768&v=2.9.11&r=stable&ec=5&o=30&fbp=fb.1.1561590071911.1130941915&it=1573513828184&coo=false&rqm=GET&dt=xvqkv3n6vjrbteho4q8wgday9qc3vnhj`
I haven't set metrics.context anywhere